# How to create HTML template using map()?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm playing around with E-commerce application. I have API call, api call returns Data like below, I want to paint all images inside `products` to HTML using `map` function, now it's returns single generated element, what I am doing wrong? thanks in advance

```js
var Result = {
  purchases: [{
      products: [{
          product_id: 264772179145,
          name: "Acer Chromebook 315 15.6",
          image_url: "https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"
        },
        {
          product_id: 264772179145,
          name: "Acer Chromebook 315 15.6",
          image_url: "https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"
        },
      ],
      timestamp: 1618215999,
      amount: 73457
    },
    {
      products: [{
        product_id: 264772179145,
        name: "Acer Chromebook 315 15.6",
        image_url: "https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"
      }],
      timestamp: 1618216092,
      amount: 73457
    },
    {
      products: [{
        product_id: 154061997658,
        name: "adidas Wheeled Team Bag Men`s",
        image_url: "https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/JYAAAOSwwRZf9n2L/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"
      }],
      timestamp: 1618217956,
      amount: 34566
    }
  ],
};

function getProducts() {
  var res;
  var purchases = Result.purchases.map(purchases => {
    var x = purchases.amount;
    res = purchases.products.map(el => {
      return `<div class="all-img"><img style="height:50px"; width:50px; src="${el.image_url}">
                  <div class="amount">${x}</div>
              </div>`
    })
  })
  document.getElementById("transactionBoxes").innerHTML = res.join('')
}
```

```html
<div id="transactionBoxes">

</div>
<button onclick="getProducts()">append</button>
```

Comment: That's not how `.map()` is supposed to be used: `Result.purchases.map(purchases => { ... })`. The callback doesn't return anything. This will also only work when there's only one element in `Result.purchases` (your actual problem). Replace the `.map()` calls with `.forEach()` + `.push()` or have a look at `.flatMap()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shortened the function so you won't have to use the `return` keyword and the extra variables

```js
var Result = {"purchases":[{"products":[{"product_id":264772179145,"name":"Acer Chromebook 315 15.6","image_url":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"},{"product_id":264772179145,"name":"Acer Chromebook 315 15.6","image_url":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"},{"product_id":264772179145,"name":"Acer Chromebook 315 15.6","image_url":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"},{"product_id":264772179145,"name":"Acer Chromebook 315 15.6","image_url":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"}],"timestamp":1618215999,"amount":73457},{"products":[{"product_id":264772179145,"name":"Acer Chromebook 315 15.6","image_url":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"}],"timestamp":1618216092,"amount":73457},{"products":[{"product_id":154061997658,"name":"adidas Wheeled Team Bag Men`s","image_url":"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/JYAAAOSwwRZf9n2L/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F"}],"timestamp":1618217956,"amount":34566}]};

function getProducts() {
  const purchases = Result.purchases.map(purchase => purchase.products.map(el => `<div class="all-img"><img style="height:50px"; width:50px; src="${el.image_url}"><div class="amount">${purchase.amount}</div></div>`).join(''));
  
  document.getElementById("transactionBoxes").innerHTML = purchases.join('');
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getProducts);
```

```html
<div id="transactionBoxes"></div>
<button>append</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve two things here:

1. You can nest `map` functions to be sure to render your whole collection
2. `style="height:50px"; width:50px;` => `style="height:50px; width:50px;"`

```js
    var Result = {
      purchases: [
        {
          products: [
            {
              product_id: 264772179145,
              name: 'Acer Chromebook 315 15.6',
              image_url: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F',
            },
            {
              product_id: 264772179145,
              name: 'Acer Chromebook 315 15.6',
              image_url: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F',
            },
          ],
          timestamp: 1618215999,
          amount: 73457,
        },
        {
          products: [
            {
              product_id: 264772179145,
              name: 'Acer Chromebook 315 15.6',
              image_url: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/EAcAAOSw6pJe8Lwo/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F',
            }],
          timestamp: 1618216092,
          amount: 73457,
        },
        {
          products: [
            {
              product_id: 154061997658,
              name: "adidas Wheeled Team Bag Men's",
              image_url: 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/JYAAAOSwwRZf9n2L/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F',
            }],
          timestamp: 1618217956,
          amount: 34566,
        },
      ],
    };
    
    function getProducts() {
          var res = Result.purchases
            .map((purchases) => {
              return purchases.products
                .map((product) => {
                  return (`
                <div class="all-img">
                  <img style="height:50px; width:50px;" src="${product.image_url}" alt="${product.name}" />
                    <div class="amount">${purchases.amount}</div>
                </div>
              `)
                })
                .join('')
            })
            .join('');
          document.getElementById('transactionBoxes').innerHTML = res;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="transactionBoxes"></div>
    <button onclick="getProducts()">append</button>
```

You should also read the [map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you tried to use it as a `for`/`forEach` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the return statement with parentheses. I program in React Native and it is required to surround the return with parentheses if it has multiple lines.

```
res = purchases.products.map(el => {
        return (`<div class="all-img"><img style="height:50px"; width:50px; src="${el.image_url}">
                   <div class="amount">${x}</div>
                 </div>`)
    })
```

Comment: They are not necessary here, because there's only one long template string that has no problems with multiple lines.